# Django create db table headers from dict

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a `model.Model` with the columnheaders(key) and types(value). I tried it with the `setattr(self,columnheader,columntype)` but this seems to not work. Can i dynamically alter the table with django inbuilts or do i have to use raw sql?

**Example dict:**

```
_dict = { "column_1": models.IntegerField(),
"column_2": models.IntegerField()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign this to the local variables, but I would advise against this:

```
_dict = {
    'column_1': models.IntegerField(),
    'column_2': models.IntegerField()
}

class MyModel(models.Model):
    locals().update(_dict)
```